# DataTable's destroy() method does not destroy initialization arguments?

Tags: datatables, destroy

I ran into a problem with destroying DataTable instance.
After applying `destroy()` method, the initialization object is not cleared up completely - while `data` property is cleaned, the `aaData` property stays the same (`aaData` is a synonym to `data` used for compatibility with previous DataTables version). And as the result `DataTables` draws the old (destroyed) table.
Should I use something besides `destroy()`? Or just manually reset `aaData`?

https://jsfiddle.net/s976/uxrknum3/

```
var data1 = [
{"name":"John", "age": 13},
{"name":"Mike", "age": 14}
];

var data2 = [
{"name":"Tom", "age": 15}
];

var args = {
    "columns" : [
                {"data": "name", "title": "Name"},
                {"data": "age", "title": "Age"}
            ],
  "data"  : data1
};

var table = $(test).DataTable(args);
table.destroy();
args.data = data2;
//args.aaData = args.data; //Uncomment this line for proper behavior
table = $(test).DataTable(args);
```

Comment: After posting the question I realized that it's a normal behavior. `destroy()` destroys only the table instance, not the arguments. However this may cause a serious headache, since `DataTables` alters the argument object without saying about it to developer :)

Comment: Yes, dataTables enriches the initialisation object literal with some defaults and a double set of properties to support the underlying hungarian notation.  I do not know any jQuery plugin that also destroys its initialisation params (dont even know if that is possible at all?) If you have spotted out a leak I will suggest you report it to the author.  I have seen elsewhere that he is really careful about memory leaks and "heap-care".

Comment: You _could_ initialise with `var table = $(test).DataTable($.extend({}, args))` headache relieved :)